# Spring-Lemon auth token expiration

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, spring-lemon

I use Spring-Lemon library for my spring boot project. I use a web front-end to my application. My question is, how to know if my auth token is about to expire? Documentation said a Get context operation should be used in this case to get a new token. But I did't find the way to find out when I should use this method to get a new token. Is there way to add the expiration date or the time remained to the responses, so my front-end would know that it should renew the token?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing when it'll expire shouldn't be a problem, because you actually control it:

1. By default, the expiration will be 10 days after you call
   /context (See `LemonProperties`)
2. You can change it by [setting a
   property](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon/wiki/Getting-Started-With-Spring-Lemon#setting-up-applicationyml)
3. You override the property be calling get-context with a
   parameter: /context?expirationMillis=123456

Comment: I see that, that's ok. But how should my front-end know it's time to call /context? I log in, save the token in local storage, 9 days pass then I reopen the site. I should renew the token, but how will the front-end know it? Should I store a date with it? If this is the case when I change the server side setting, I should change a front-end setting too for the right calculation. I thought there is a way to add the remaining time to responses, so the front-end would always know when it's about to refresh. (For example, if less then a day remained.)